# Magento2 block returns empty template ( Renderer list for block "cart\grid_0" is not defined error)

Tags: ajax, magento, magento2

I am trying to make an Ajax call. The page is calling a function "UpdatePost" in Checkout/Cart, and it updates the cart and reloads. I wold like to return total prices on the page.

This code returns only an empty content ["content"=>""].
When I rewrite the form.phtml without PHP code, it loads the page without problem.

Do you have any suggestions to make it work?

I have received  Renderer list for block "cart\grid_0" is not defined error.

```
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);

    $block = $this->_view->getLayout(); 
    ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Checkout\Cart\Grid')
    ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::cart/form.phtml');

    $data = ['content' => $block->toHtml()];

    $resultJson->setData($data);

    return     $resultJson;
```

Comment: ^^^ you shouldnt have that semicolon after ->getLayout();

Answer (score 0):

Your block declaration has a typo (semicolon after ->getLayout();

```
$block = $this->_view->getLayout(); 
->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Checkout\Cart\Grid')
->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::cart/form.phtml');
```

Should be;

```
 $block = $this->_view->getLayout()
->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Checkout\Cart\Grid')
->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::cart/form.phtml');
```

You should also be setting the template within your blocks _construct method, after parent::_construct, if present;

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::cart/form.phtml');
}
```